# Primefaces Extensions Timeline auto value of height does not work

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I'm using timeline component of primefaces extensions and when i set height of the component "auto", there is no any visual view of the component on the page on the other hand when i set the height a value, it seen successfully. But row count (group count in demo) of the component is dynamic on my application. I found a solution by counting row count before rendering and set height value of component in xhtml using a getter method which provide a calculated height value.

V. 0.6.1

Why auto value of height paremeter does not work? Is there any idea and any optimum solution?

```
<pe:timeline id="timeline" value="#{scheduleBean.timelines}" 
     axisPosition="top"  
     eventStyle="box"  
     var="event"
     height="auto" width="100%" widgetVar="timelineWidget">
```

http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/timeline/advancedUsage.jsf

Comment: default height is auto, how it looks without setting it?

Comment: it isn't different, same situation with auto value

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: First i did not set value to get default valuue as auto then i set it "auto". Bot doesn't work for that version. Why I'm getting downvote? There was a bug that I post below.

Answer (score 0):

I open an issue to primefaces extensions developers, and they accepted it as a defect. It's the bug a bug of the component.

[Issue Link](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces-extensions/issues/detail?id=319&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary)

This issue was closed by revision [r1598.](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces-extensions/source/detail?r=1598)